# Static files not loading with spring boot web, JSPs, context-path

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot 2.7.5, Java 8 and Maven and have the following jars included in pom.xml:

- spring-boot-devtools
- spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
- spring-boot-starter-test
- spring-boot-starter-tomcat
- spring-boot-starter-web
- tiles-core
- tiles-jsp
- tomcat-embed-jasper

I want to use JQuery and DataTables. My static content is in src/main/resource/static:

```
src/main/resources
  bootstrap-5.2.2-dist/
  DataTables/
  jquery-ui-1.13.2.custom/
  jquery-3.6.1.min.js
  myapp.css
  myapp.js
```

I have a configuration class that has this

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { ... })
public class ApplicationConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer
{
@Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(
    ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
  {
    registry//
      .addResourceHandler("/static/**")//
      .addResourceLocations("/static/");
  }
}
```

In my JSP, I have tried the following, none of which work

- `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.13.2.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`
- `<script type="text/javascript" src="static/jquery-ui-1.13.2.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`
- `<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery-ui-1.13.2.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

In my application.properties, I have this:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/content/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
server.servlet.context-path=/myapp
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: You don't seem to have a dependency for jquery in your pom. Anyway,  the jquery library should be placed under webjars (e.g `<script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`. I'm personally not using jsp, but rather Thymeleaf but I still think this should work for you as well.

Comment: I've never had jquery in any pom, since it's a javascript-only solution. I'm not using webjars. Just downloading the compressed js files.

Comment: have you checked the network tab in your browser (in development tools)? What does it say?

Comment: are all the other resources found under /static loaded properly (besides jquery and datatables)?

Comment: maybe you are missing some points or typo. so check that basic example please -> https://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-with-static-content-css-and-javascript-js

Comment: The network tab has a bunch of these type of messages: "Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8088/myapp/jquery-ui-1.13.2.custom/jquery-ui.min.js”." It looks like no js file loads.

Comment: @muhammed ozbilici, yes I looked at that page and several others. Oddly that page doesn't mention anything about an ApplicationConfiguration class or an ApplicationInitializer class, whereas most others do. I think I'm too close to the problem now and can't step back and see the one stupid thing I need to change.

Comment: @Gary Kephart, it's possibly a security issue then. Check you web security (WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implementation) and make sure that everything under /static is accessible (resources found under /static should normally be made accessible even when a user in not authenticated). Or you can make only certain folders under static accessible for unauthenticated users)

Comment: I don't have any security configured. This is eventually going to be microservices and using OAuth2 to connect to each other, but for now it's just one war file. It's a fairly simple system with only about 15 business objects so far. So I'm just going to use basic web security for now.

Comment: @Gary Kephart, place javascript files under /static/js folder, rather than just /static  (and css files under /static/css). I think this (sub)folder structure is actually a convention in Spring Boot. Btw, all the paths can be explicitly permitted in web security but since you're not using it, let's just try this.

Comment: I tried it with one JS file and it still failed with "Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8088/myapp/js/myapp.js”. " It would have been difficult to split jquery-ui and DataTables into separate css and js folders anyways, as they come all bundled in one parent folder. I've never had to split it before pre-spring boot and I'd be disappointed if this was now a requirement.

Comment: @Gary Kephart, can you try to load your js file from localhost:8088/js/myapp.js and see if that works?

Comment: @Gary Kephart, you may also try and replace .addResourceLocations("/static/") with .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/"). We (my company) use this kind of syntax but I'm not sure if it's going to make any difference.

Comment: I did try and load it that way, but with no success. I did find a way, though. See my answer.

Comment: I will try the "classpath:/static/"

Comment: It looks like this works as well! I think I'm keeping it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to make it work. Not the best answer, but it is *an* answer (cue Wheel of Time quote):

I moved the static folder directly under the webapp folder. I then changed the script and link tags to have the src/href start with "static/".

I have no idea why this works but am still open to finding the right way to do it.

Comment: In my "class ApplicationConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer" I changed addResourceHandlers() to addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/") at the suggestion of dsp_user and that also works.

Comment: Note that @EnableWebMvc has some effect on this stuff also.